# Matrix inequalities

Tags: matrices, inequality

We know that for a complex number $x=a+ib , \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have the following inequality

$$|x|\leq |a|+|b|$$
Question:

Do we have a matrix version of the above inequality?
i.e. can we find two matrix $A$ and $B$ which $X=A
+iB$ does not hold in this inequality

$$|X|\leq |A|+|B|$$where $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Here |A|, means the square root of a matrix which is defined by $|A|=\sqrt{A^{*}A}$ .

I am looking for a counterexample...

Thanks in advanced

Comment: What does the order $\le$ mean for matrices?

Comment: Do you really mean $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$? Or the usual norm $|A| = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} A^* A}$? If the former then I guess $M \le N$ means $N - M$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: yes I mean $A\leq B$ whenever $B-A$ is positive semidefinite. but we can also compare these two matrices with their eigenvalues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random counterexample: try $$A = \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-2&-3\\ -2&0&0
\\ -3&0&-1\end {array} \right] 
,\ B = \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&1&0\\ 1&0&1
\\ 0&1&3\end {array} \right],\ 
X = \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-2+i&-3\\-2+i&0&i
\\ -3&i&-1+3\,i\end {array} \right] 
$$
Maple gives me (approximately)
$$ 
|A|+|B|-|X|= 
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc}  1.1394&- 0.25339+ 0.17463\,i&
 0.14346- 1.5302\,i\\ - 0.25339- 0.17463\,i& 0.98155
& 0.41758+ 0.69470\,i\\  0.14346+ 1.5302\,i& 0.41758
- 0.69470\,i& 2.1207\end {array} \right] 
$$
which has eigenvalues
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{c}  3.46588217419216527\\ -
 0.192448780996627683\\  0.968241166804460041
\end {array} \right] 
$$

EDIT: There are also $2 \times 2$ examples, such as 
$$ A = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 3&0\\ 0&0\end {array}
 \right] 
,\
B =   \left[ \begin {array}{cc} -1&3\\ 3&2\end {array}
 \right]
$$
with
$$ |A|+|B|-|X|=  \left[ \begin {array}{cc}  1.956443066& 0.0500626101+ 1.191452956\,i
\\  0.0500626101- 1.191452956\,i& 0.1979586323
\end {array} \right] 
$$
which has eigenvalues
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{c}  2.558799068\\ -
 0.404397368\end {array} \right] 
$$

EDIT:  As requested, here is Maple code.

```
with(LinearAlgebra);
A := <<3,0>|<0,0>>;
B := <<-1,3>|<3,2>>;
X := A + I*B;
absA := MatrixFunction(evalf(A^2), sqrt(t),t);
absB := MatrixFunction(evalf(B^2), sqrt(t),t);
absX := MatrixFunction(evalf(X . X^%H), sqrt(t),t);
d:= absA + absB - absX;
E:= Eigenvalues(d);
```

Comment: Did you consider square root for above matrices?

Comment: Yes, I believe I did it correctly.

Comment: No need for email: I'll include the Maple code.